# Set server output only in spool

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Is it possible to set the server output only into the spool file and not in the shell ?

```
set serveroutput on
spool log.txt
exec MY_PROCEDURE();
spool off
```

Inside `MY_PROCEDURE` I have this :

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Hello World');
```

I would like to put `Hello World` only in `log.txt`, not in the screen shell.

Comment: How are you running this; as a script with `start` or `@`, or interactively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to pipe the unix output to /dev/null

```
$ sqlplus -S user/password @test.sql > /dev/null
$ cat test.sql 
set serveroutput on
set feedback off
spool log.txt
exec dbms_output.put_line('This is great!! and working');
spool off;
exit;
$ cat log.txt 
This is great!! and working                                                     
$
```

Answer (score 0):

The sqlplus way to do this, if you run it as script, is to set 'termout' ot ON or OFF.
Output is always spooled to a file, if spooling is activated, the output is written to the terminal (more exactly to stdout on Linux) if TERMOUT is ON, which is the default. So to suppress the output  do

```
set serveroutput on
spool log.txt
set termout off
exec MY_PROCEDURE();
set termout on
spool off
```